# Horizontal and vertical pointer speeds sometimes don't match

Tags: arch-linux, kde, mouse

So, here's a fun one: Arbitrarily, when I log into my user, the vertical mouse sensitivity is much lower than the horizontal, about half as much. In these situations, the horizontal sensitivity is the expected, but vertically is lower than my setting. When this happens, changing the sensitivity in the system settings makes no difference to this proportion.

This happens roughly 50% of the time, apparently at random. I have not been able to identify any way of influence which behaviour will take place. Once I've logged in, the sensitivity is either correct or incorrect for the remainder of the session.

My mouse is a Logitech G600, which I have configured its onboard memory to use the full 8200dpi, and then I have a very low "pointer speed" value in the system settings.

Interestingly, it seems that this sensitivity is per user, as the login screen doesn't display this issue, but has a much higher pointer speed (this is fine by me, just stating the evidence)

I don't have even the faintest idea how to debug this, let alone fix it. I would like to not have to roll a bunch of dice every time I turn the computer on to have a working mouse.

Output of `xinput --list-props` for the mouse, in either situation.

```
Device Enabled (154):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (282):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (283):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (284):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (285):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (286):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (287): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (288): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (289):    0
libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (290):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (291):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (292):    0
libinput Accel Speed (293): -0.800000
libinput Accel Speed Default (294): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (295):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (296):   0, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (297):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (298): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (299): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event3"
Device Product ID (271):    1133, 49738
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (301):   1
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (302):    15
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (303):    15
libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (304):    1
```

Comment: A/ Use *xinput --list* to get the id of your mouse then B/ *xinput --list-props the_id_you_collected* in order to view the line dedicated to the *Coordinate Transformation Matrix*. Can you notice differences in the two situations you describe ?

Comment: @MC68020 Sorry for the delay. No, the outputs of `xinput --list-props the_mouses_id` are identical (checked with `diff`)